# Regex: match anything but a group

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-group

I have text formatted like this:

```
(delimiter)
111111
(delimiter)
222222
(delimiter)
333333
(delimiter)
```

Where (delimiter) is a character group and 111111,222222,333333 - some random text, which does not include (delimiter) group.

Is there any way to write a regexp like "(delimiter) <*anything,but a delimiter*> (delimiter)"?

I expect capturing groups like this:

```
"(delimiter)
111111
(delimiter)",

"(delimiter)
222222
(delimiter)",

"(delimiter)
333333
(delimiter)"
```

More specifically,
In my case delimiter is `([0-9]{1,2}[\s][A-z]+[\s][0-9]{4}[\s])`
I tried to use negative lookahead like this:

```
(([0-9]{1,2}[\s][A-z]+[\s][0-9]{4}[\s])(?!([0-9]{1,2}[\s][A-z]+[\s][0-9]{4}[\s]))([0-9]{1,2}[\s][A-z]+[\s][0-9]{4}[\s]))
```

But that doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: do you use any programming language with it?

Comment: @JBone, I want to write script on javascript

Comment: ok that makes it easy. Let me write it

Comment: Is delimiter a string or a single character? If it's a single character, use `[^X]*` where `X` is the character.

Comment: @Barmar (delimiter) is a character group

Comment: Then I think you need to use a negative lookahead.

Comment: @Barmar, I tried, but looks like I don't understand how to use it right.

Comment: Show what you tried, we'll help you fix it.

Comment: @Barmar 
`(([0-9]{1,2}[\s][A-z]+[\s][0-9]{4}[\s])(?!([0-9]{1,2}[\s][A-z]+[\s][0-9]{4}[\s]))([0-9]{1,2}[\s][A-z]+[\s][0-9]{4}[\s]))`
([0-9]{1,2}[\s][A-z]+[\s][0-9]{4}[\s]) is a delimiter

Comment: Put it in the question.

Comment: Where is the delimiter string in there?

Comment: @Barmar, Added to the question

Comment: `RegExp.match()` won't return overlapping matches. The end delimiter of one group won't be returned as the starting delimiter of the next group.

Comment: Do you really need to return the delimiters, or just what's between them?

Comment: @Barmar No, I don't need to delimiters.
"RegExp.match() won't return overlapping matches."
Does that mean that just 
`([0-9]{1,2}[\s][A-z]+[\s][0-9]{4}[\s])[\s\S]*([0-9]{1,2}[\s][A-z]+[\s][0-9]{4}[\s])`
 should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression as the delimiter in the string `split()` method. It will return all the values between the delimiters.

```js
let string = `12 Dec 2019
111111
13 Dec 2019
222222
14 Dec 2019
333333
15 Dec 2019
`;

let result = string.split(/\s*[0-9]{1,2}\s[A-Z]+\s[0-9]{4}\s/i);
console.log(result);
```

I changed `[A-z]` to `[A-Z]` and add the `i` modifier to make it case-insensitive. There's also no need for `[]` around `\s`.

Comment: `[A-z]+` is most likely a typo, it must be `[A-Za-z]+`